Nonexistence of short integer program sequence which generates squares - II
Is there a way to show within a mixed integer linear program with constant number of integer variables, $poly(\log B)$ number of real variables and constraints of length $poly(\log B)$ (say length $\leq10^{100}\log B$), it is not possible for an integer variable to take exactly all the square values up to a bound $B$?
If we have a sequence of such programs, as $B\rightarrow\infty$, we can get non-uniform $ETH$ violation or even $NP\subseteq P/Poly$. How can we be sure such a sequence of constant number of integer variable and poly number of real variables and constraint programs does not exist?
Note I am not looking for consequences. Of course if we can falsify these then we cannot have such programs. But the question here should be easier.
Is this related to non-existence of multiplication in some extension of Presburger arithmetic?
